# load Js file in HTML

Tags: javascript, cordova

My first PhoneGap application includes 2 HTML files.

The first one is named `index.html` which uses `index.js`. This file will display a list item. When I click an item in that list, it brings me to `detail.html` file by this:

```
   $.mobile.changePage("detail.html", { transition: "slideup"});
```

OR

```
   location.href = "detail.html";
```

On the `detail.html` page, I load `detal.js`. However it did not work. I could not use functions in `detail.js`.

Please give me your advise and there are any example ?

> Capture Photo
>
> ```
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" />
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/getAbstract.min.css" />
>     <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="js/jquery.ba-dotimeout.js"></script>
>     <script src="js/jquery.dst.js"></script>
>
>     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
>
>
> </head>
> <body>
>
>     <div data-role = "page" data-theme = "a" id = "pageContainer">
>         <!--Start Page Header -->
>         <div data-role = "header" id = "pageHeader" data-nobackbtn = "true" data-position = "fixed">
>             <h1>Camera</h1>
>         </div>
>         <!--End Page Header -->
>
>         <!--Start Page Content-->
>         <div data-role = "content" id= "pageContent">
>             <a data-role = "button" id = "btnCaptureEdit" href = "">Capture Edit</a>
>             <a data-role = "button" id = "btnLibraryPhoto" href = "">Get Photo From Library</a>
>             <a data-role = "button" id = "btnAlbumPhoto" href = "">Get Photo From Album</a>
>         </div>
>         <!--End Page Content-->
>
>         <!--Start Page Footer-->
>         <div data-role = "footer" id = "pageFooter">
>         </div>
>         <!--End Page Footer-->
>
>     </div>
>     <script src="js/detail.js"></script>
>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Can you post your code please? Particularly detail.html.

Comment: All your script tags should have type attributes.  The last script tag in the head is empty and could be removed.

Answer (score 10):

If this is your `detail.html` I don't see where do you load `detail.js`?
Maybe this

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

should be this

```
<script src="js/detail.js"></script>
```

?

Comment: I loaded <script src="js/detail.js"></script> at bottom. you can see.

Comment: When i run detail.html file in web browser, it worked well, but when i run iphone simulator, it did not work.

Comment: I can not call button event in detail.js file. Detail.js: var btnCaptureVar = $('#btnCapture');

btnCaptureVar.click(function()
{
        alert("test");
});

Comment: Make sure that you are waiting for the page to load. Use `$(document).ready(function(){ <YOUR CODE HERE> });`

Comment: I used location.href = "detail.html"; then it work now, because mobile.changePage not load you file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found the answer.
If you use node.js with express, you need to give it its own function in order for the js file to be reached.
For example:

```
const script = path.join(__dirname, 'script.js');
const server = express().get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(script))
```